# hook up light, but end tied into attic wiring

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Easy to install to black and white wires hanging out of ceiling, BUT other end of wires hooked into existing wires in attic.  Not place for switch . Have pic

Comment: Your electrics are roughed in for a pull-chain ceiling lamp.

Comment: Can you physically run a cable from a convenient switch location to the attic? If so, we can show you how to wire it up.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where is the picture? Either edit it into your question, or post the URL and someone will be along to edit it in.